# How to archive a sliding cover image effect in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

[Slider that covers an image with another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6y14.jpg)

Has anyone an idea on how culd I archive this effecti in flutter?
Or at last point me to the right direction?
This is the page where I found it:
[Affinity Photo Website](https://affinityrevolution.com/pencil-sketch-effect/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is exactly what you need, [before_after](https://pub.dev/packages/before_after):

```
   BeforeAfter(
     beforeImage: Image.asset('assets/after.jpg'),
     afterImage: Image.asset('assets/before.jpg'),
   ),
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thanks